# I want to find the missing elements using beanshell assertion in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have two get api's which gives response code having id as one of the variables

So using Jason extractor I have extracted the id of both api with the name id1 and id2

I have used bean shell assertion to compare the two id's

The data is as such:

id1:{abc,qwe,ert,yup,iop,bnm,dff} and so on

id2 :{qwe,ert,iop,bnm,dff} like this hundreds of data is present

Is there any way to print only the missing data after comparing both the ID's using beanshell assertion, if yes please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I'm not going to "help you out" with Beanshell and provide a Groovy-based solution instead.

Example code:

```
def id1 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(vars.get('id1'), '{', '}').split(',').collect()
def id2 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(vars.get('id2'), '{', '}').split(',').collect()

def missing = org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.disjunction(id1, id2)
```

And demo:

[image]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: I have tried this but the missing values isn't shown got this error ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class: Script4 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320).  @user:2897748 Please hep me out